# missing field in nested SQL statement in ms access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

The following MS Access 2010 query only outputs values for FirstName, HomePhone, and ClientNumber.  It is not outputting any values for LastName.

Can anyone show me how to change it so that it outputs values for LastName also?

```
SELECT
  ActiveCustomers.FirstName
, ActiveCustomers.LastName
, tblClientAddress.HomePhone
, ActiveCustomers.ClientNumber
FROM (
  SELECT
    Clients.ClientNumber
  , Clients.FirstName
  , Clients.LastName (
      SELECT COUNT(ReferralDate) FROM IntakeTable 
      WHERE Clients.ClientNumber = IntakeTable.ClientNumber
      AND Len(ReferralDate & '') > 0
    ) AS IntakeCount
  , (
    SELECT COUNT(ExitDate)
    FROM ExitTable
    WHERE Clients.ClientNumber = ExitTable.ClientNumber
    AND Len(ExitDate & '') > 0
  ) AS ExitCount
  FROM Clients
) AS ActiveCustomers
INNER JOIN tblClientAddress
ON ActiveCustomers.ClientNumber = tblClientAddress.ClientNumber
WHERE ActiveCustomers.IntakeCount > [ExitCount]
AND tblClientAddress.CurrentResidence = True;
```

Comment: Remember, when we discussed this query previously I advised against using the intake and exit date _counts_ to find the active customers and instead recommended using their _last intake_ and _last exit_ dates. See my previous answer for the reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing a comma after `Clients.LastName`.  Try:

```
SELECT ActiveCustomers.FirstName, ActiveCustomers.LastName, tblClientAddress.HomePhone, ActiveCustomers.ClientNumber
FROM 
       (SELECT Clients.ClientNumber, 
               Clients.FirstName, 
               Clients.LastName,
               (SELECT COUNT(ReferralDate) FROM IntakeTable WHERE Clients.ClientNumber = IntakeTable.ClientNumber AND Len(ReferralDate & '') > 0) AS IntakeCount,
               (SELECT COUNT(ExitDate) FROM ExitTable WHERE Clients.ClientNumber = ExitTable.ClientNumber AND Len(ExitDate & '') > 0) AS ExitCount 
        FROM Clients) AS ActiveCustomers
INNER JOIN tblClientAddress ON ActiveCustomers.ClientNumber = tblClientAddress.ClientNumber 
WHERE (((ActiveCustomers.IntakeCount)>[ExitCount]) AND 
       ((tblClientAddress.CurrentResidence)=True));
```

**EDIT:**

It seems likely that:

- You have a many-to-one (or one-to-many) relationship between `Clients` and `tblClientAddress`, and you have two records on the "many" side.  If you are getting duplicate records, you could add a `DISTINCT` or a `GROUP BY`,

And/Or:

- That the `(SELECT COUNT(` subqueries are somehow messing up their parent query, and need to be modified so that they can go into their parent query's `FROM` clause with an `Inner Join`, e.g.:

  `(SELECT ClientNumber, COUNT(ReferralDate) as IntakeCount FROM IntakeTable WHERE Len(ReferralDate & '') > 0 GROUP BY ClientNumber) AS qryIntakeCount`

Comment: @MontyWild Thank you. +1 for the fast and helpful response.  That got LastName to populate, but the query is returning two rows for each record, which is wrong.  It should only return one row for each record.  Can you tell us how to fix this problem?

Comment: @MontyWild Yes, there was a one to many relationship, and some of the records had multiple addresses marked as CurrentResidence=True.  This works now, so I am marking yours as the answer.